# Does "business logic" mean formulation of business by logic?

Tags: logic

I have heard that ethics can be formulated by logic. So I guess there are many things which can be formulated by logic.

Is it the same case for business? Does "business logic" mean  formulation of business by logic? How is the formulation done roughly?

Thanks.

Comment: It can. Business strategy is often a loosely worked out piece of reasoning. Also, see work of firms like Renaissance Technologies which use statistical arbitrage. Their business logic is, in strictest sense, a logic.

Comment: I'm an analyst for a Fortune 10 company, and as an analyst, my job description entails using the specifics of my technical and industry knowledge to reason about what constitutes a good choice to ensure proper performance, continuity, and adaptibility of my processes in alignment with organizational goals. Businness logic is my reasoning process drawing from technical, legal, and business knowledge to make good decisions. If a superior comes to me and says, why did you do such and such, I have to have a defensible justification that draws on policies and procedures, knowledge of contracts, etc

Answer (score 5):

Not really.

The expression 'business logic' is normally used when specifying business functionality required of software (e.g. generate an invoice amount by multiplying transactions by transaction fees).

I guess it could also be used as a synonym for something like 'commercial rationale' or 'industrial logic', e.g. the business logic of bancassurance is for banks to cross sell insurance products to their customers.

Neither has much to do with logic in sense of formal logic studied by philosophers, except in the trivial sense that any valid argument should not contradict basic logical principles.

Comment: Agreed - "business logic" in software engineering (only place I've ever heard it) means "business algorithms" or "business code": the rules, code, instructions, etc, supporting the flow and processing business data. This is often used to distinguish it from the rest of the code supporting UI, security, connectivity and all the rest of the glue necessary in a program or platform. e.g. 'authorize a loan if credit score > 700' is business logic, 'if loan is authorized, send a mail' might be, but the code actually sending the mail (connecting to the mail server, etc). wouldn't be.